# How to connect to Excel xls file from Access 2010 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have googled alot for this but I couldn't get to it ..

I have an excel file (.xls) that is around 13K rows .. I want to be able to connect to it from the Access 2010 VBA and then be able to copy data from it that I require for my work.

Anyone suggest how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you linked the Excel file as a table?

Comment: I don't want to do this .. I have the VBA to give the user the option to choose the file through the `Application.FileDialog` .. When the user chooses the file, the VBA should select some columns to copy to a table in the database .. Later, another form will do some searches based on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query in MS Access:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xlsm].[Sheet1$] s
WHERE s.SomeField=2
```

Or

```
SELECT * INTO Table1 
FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xlsm].[Sheet1$] s
WHERE s.SomeField=2
```

You can also refer to named ranges and ranges. You can also simply set up a query and allow users to create their own make table queries.

In VBA

```
 Dim db As Database
 Set db = CurrentDB

 ssql="SELECT * INTO Table1 " _
  & "FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xlsm].[Sheet1$] s " _
  & "WHERE s.SomeField=2"
 db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: how can I do this using the VBA?

Comment: Your update gives me an error! "`run-time error '3067': Query must contain at least one table or query`" .. Also, how can I select specific columns? say columns A, B, C, E and H

Comment: I managed to solve this one, but I get another issue .. `run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.`

Comment: Well, I managed that too :) .. And was also able to select the specific columns .. Thanks very much for guiding :)